# Black screen showing after splash screen Android 2.2 onwards Cordova 1.9

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

Even my problem is not resolved....

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //fix for Bug 3774
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash); // Display splash     screen for android
       this.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 120000);
       super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",1000);// 1000 is the time for splash screen display 

   }
```

Here, I wanted splash screen will show for 1 Sec (1000) and after that index page must be shown, but in between (splash and index page), blank screen is coming for 10-20 sec.

in my apps.js,  i implemented -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
 }
```

but even it is not working.
1. I don't want to show splash screen more than 1000.
Any solution ....

**Solution**

**I was doing silly mistake.**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
 }
```

this code must be in .Ready method in .js file.

1. Java file

   I was doing silly mistake.

   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
       cordova.exec(null, null, "SplashScreen", "hide", []);
    }

this code must be in .Ready method in .js file.

1. Java file

add time to max like 10000 or 1200000

Comment: Copy your solution to an actual solution.